# Deserializar Json no C#

Tags: c#, json

Tenho pouca experiência em `ASP.NET` e `C#`, se possível gostaria de uma ajuda dos amigos. Estou com esse arquivo json:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "barcode": "36410.00035 00022.778708 00000.256370 9 00000000001100",
    "link": "https://download/v1/227787_34355_LUADRO2/227787-25637-RRAENA3",
    "billet_link": "https://visualizacao5_LUADRO2/A4XB-227787-25637-RRAENA3",
    "pdf": { "charge": "https://download._34355_LUADRO2/227787-25637-RRAENA3.pdf" },
    "expire_at": "2023-05-30",
    "charge_id": 551470555,
    "status": "waiting",
    "total": 1100,
    "payment": "banking_billet"
  }
}
```

Estou precisando capturar o dado que existe no campo: **charge**, que está dentro do campo pdf e dentro do campo data.

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz ?

Estou usando `Newtonsoft.Json`;

Comment: *"Já tentei de tudo e não consigo"* tudo o que? coloque na pergunta o que já tentou

Comment: o campo no json é `charge_id`, checou se está colocando correto (na pergunta você colocou só `charge`)

Answer (score 1):

*Para deserializar o json, você precisa criar classes aninhadas de forma que fiquem com as **propriedades iguais** aos campos do **json**. No seu caso deverá ser criadas classes aninhadas dessa forma:*

```
public class DataJson
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public Data Data { get; set; }

}
public class Data
{
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Billet_link { get; set; }
    public Pdf Pdf { get; set; }
    public string Expire_at { get; set; }
    public int Charge_id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Payment { get; set; }
}

public class Pdf
{
    public string Charge { get; set; }
}
```

*Onde a classe **DataJson** iria representa o objeto do **json**
e iria conter os campos que iriam ter dentro dele
no caso **Code** e **Data**. O **pdf** que é o que você precisa é um objeto **Pdf** que contem o campo **charge**, e esse objeto está dentro da classe Data.*

Depois só deserializar dessa forma:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJson>(json);
```

- ***Obs**: Lembre-se que se você não quiser todos os campos do json, basta somente ter os necessários retirando os que não precisa.*
- ***Dica**: Ao publicar uma duvida no **fórum**, lembre-se também de compartilhar o código que está criando, para facilitar a resolução do problema.*